# Azure AD which is configured with Azure AD connector is Down then user are able to login with their laptop and they can reset their password

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Suppose my AD is incidentally down which is configure with Azure AD (Hybrid model). I have only one AD server with configured Azure AD connector. So, user can able to login in their laptop or they can reset or disable their password and account?

Answer (score 0):

If your on-premises Active Directory (AD) is down in a hybrid model with Azure AD, the impact on user authentication and password-related operations depends on various factors.

- If you have [Password Hash Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/hybrid/connect/whatis-phs) set as your authentication mode than your users should be able to login without any issues.
- However, if you have authentication method as Federation or Pass through Auth then user might not be able to login as the on-premises server would not be available.
- Password writeback to your local AD will fail for sync'd users, limiting your user's password reset ability.
- You might not be able to change user account status on local AD and sync them to Azure AD.
- You should be able to disable sync'd user account from Azure AD, however be informed that as soon as your Local AD is back up and running user account status from local AD would be sync'd to Azure AD.